# ConTeXt \quote command resets font shape. Is this a bug?

Tags: context, punctuation

Whenever I use `\quote` command, it resets font shape to upright (while `\quotation` command works as expected). I suppose it's a bug.
Here's the minimal example:

```
\starttext
{\bf Font shape \quote{does} change}.\par
{\it Font shape \quote{does} change}.\par
{\bf Font shape \quotation{stays} as expected}.
\stoptext
```

[image: ConTeXt code]

Is this really a bug or I misuse the command?

Comment: This looks like a bug. You should report it to the mailing list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to the (bad, IMHO) default configuration for `quote` and can be changed using:

```
\setupdelimitedtext[quote][style=]
```

The default is `style=normal`, which resets the font to upright; leaving out a style specification with `style=` inherits the current style.